# I want to restart my watterfall dialog at it's beginning when it ends, using C#

Tags: dialog, botframework, reset, cortana

I'm using the Bot Framework .Net SDK4.
I start my Dialog at `MainDialog`.
I'm trying to restart my dialog when the watterfall dialog conversation ends. I have multiple watterfall that redirect to other watterfall dialogs, unti they reach the final one.
When I'm using `stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken)` or `stepContext.CancellAllDialogsAsync(cancellationToken)`, the dialog just returns to the previous parent dialog. 
I also can't just use `BeginDialogAsync(nameof(MainDialog), null, cancellationToke)` because of circular dependency issues.
Is there anything I can do to restart my dialog at `MainDialog`, where it reruns tehe dialog again.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```cs
 return await sc.ReplaceDialogAsync(nameof(NoUnderstandDialog), cancellationToken);
```

To restart the waterfall dialog you are currently in.

**ReplaceDialogAsync** :

> Starts a new dialog and replaces on the stack the currently active dialog with
>                the new one. This is particularly useful for creating loops or redirecting to
>               another dialog.

You can use this for multiple reasons, validation for example if the user inputs a wrong value, you can restart the dialog to prompt again. Be careful though your waterfall dialog should always "ends" meaning it should have a **EndDialogAsync** so you don't get stuck in an endless loop

Comment: I don't know if I phrased my question correctly, but what I wish to do is go to the beginning of the conversation (to `MainDialog`), not the current dialog.

Comment: Oops sorry, I managed to make it work. Thank you anyway for the quick response